# javascript add multidimensional array values to new array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an multidimensional array like

```
var arr = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[1,1,1]];
```

and I would like to add up what would be a matrix column for each column into a new array. The result I am expect would be [3,6,6].  This is the solution I came up with

```
function compute(arr) {
    var X = _.reduce(arr, function(acc, j) {
        acc += j[0];
        return acc;
    },0);
    var Y = _.reduce(arr, function(acc, k) {
        acc += k[1];
        return acc;
    },0);
    var Z = _.reduce(arr, function(acc, l) {
        acc += l[2];
        return acc;
    },0);
    return [X,Y,Z];
}
```

It is working but seems redudent to have 3 reduce functions.  I am looking for a cleaner, more functional, faster solution using lodash.

I was thinking maybe I could use the _.flatten function since you can pass it a function for each iteration but I can't seem to avoid all the looping.  Any suggestions?

Comment: base something off of a callback instead of an anon, so you can do return _.map([0,1,2], sumCounter);

Comment: It seems LoDash doesn't have `zipWith`, too bad...

Comment: zipWith is exactly what I'm looking for. haha too bad. Should rewrite this in haskell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple way using vanilla to avoid an inner anon:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[1,1,1]];

function sum(a,b){return a+b;}
function pluck(a){return a[this];}


arr.map(function(a,b,c){
   return c.map(pluck,b).reduce(sum);
}); // == [3, 6, 6]
```

the same in underscore/lodash:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[1,1,1]];   

function sum(a,b){return a+b;}

_.map(arr, function(a,b,c){
  return _.reduce(_.pluck(c, b), sum);
}); // == [3, 6, 6]
```

personally, i like the native chaining of the Array methods, so i don't have to balance parens, but either way works.

it nicer to use different low-level interchangeable parts than one big procedure so that you can reduce, re-use, and recycle your keystrokes as you find yourself needing to do almost the same thing again later.

Comment: This answer requires a square matrix to work properly. To see a failure, either add another triple to the array, or remove the last triple of the array. Or see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/icognivator/pojg9xmj/1/. I realize this answer is old, but I figured this comment would be helpful for anyone who stumbles on this SO topic... it's one of the only ones dealing with matrix addition in lodash. One final note... as of v3.8, lodash includes _.zipWith.

Comment: @SteveHenty: in that case, you can simply swap the inner and the outer: https://jsfiddle.net/xsozsox4/

Comment: funny you should mention that solution... it's the same one I came up with here, albeit in lodash 4.x semantics: https://jsfiddle.net/icognivator/gcxx59L7/. It still feels a little 'hacky' relying on an arbitrary array element for the number of columns, and on a closure to have access to the complete array... but it works.

Comment: A final note... lodash offers a chaining syntax to more closely approximate the native 'readability' : https://jsfiddle.net/icognivator/fjvk9oeq/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a function inside your function that handles your index and your array:

```
function compute(arr) {

    var reduce = function (index) {
        return _.reduce(arr, function(acc, array) {
            acc += array[index];
            return acc;
        },0);
    }

    var X = reduce(0);
    var Y = reduce(1);
    var Z = reduce(2);

    return [X,Y,Z];
};
```

If you want to make it a bit shorter, you could also just to this:

```
function compute(arr) {
    var reduce = function (index) {
        return _.reduce(arr, function(acc, array) {
            acc += array[index];
            return acc;
        },0);
    }

    return [reduce(0), reduce(1), reduce(2)];
};
```

If you want to make it a even shorter, you could also just to this. This one is a bit more functional because you're passing in the function as an argument to `_.map`

```
function compute(arr) {
    var reduce = function (index) {
        return _.reduce(arr, function(acc, array) {
            acc += array[index];
            return acc;
        },0);
    }
    return _.map([0, 1, 2], reduce);
};
```

You can check out the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/thejsj/p33hmc8q/